# Inconsistent behaviour when creating a KeyVault key via an Azure PowerShell Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

When attempting to create a KeyVault key via an Azure PowerShell Function I am experiencing inconsistent behaviour. It seems that running identical PowerShell on different function hosts will return different results/failures. The failure is a variant of the following:

*_Get-AzureRmKeyVault : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRmAccount to set up your Azure credentials.*

The script is designed to authenticate to Azure via an Azure AD service principal, get the relevant KeyVault and create a key within it. But, even when hard-coding all the values for troubleshooting, the inconsistency still exists across differing function hosts i.e. one creates a KeyVault key successfully, whereas the other fails.

```
$ServicePrincipalPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$ServicePrincipalCredential = New-Object     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ServicePrincipalAppId, $ServicePrincipalPassword)
$Login = Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $ServicePrincipalCredential
$KeyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "testkeyvault"
write-output "$($KeyVault.VaultURI)"
$Key = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName -Name 'testkey' -Destination Software
$KeyUrl = $Key.id.Substring(0, $Key.id.LastIndexOf("/"))
Write-Output $KeyUrl
```

Is this behaviour expected or anything I can do to make the experience consistent?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you opened an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1827

It's probably some bug in the runtime and that's the appropriate place to open a tracking issue. Please avoid double posting in the future

Comment: Apologies, I was not sure where best to log/track the issue. Would the current recommendation be to migrate the functionality to Azure Automation until such time that Azure PowerShell Functions are not classed as "experimental"?

Comment: no worries. If you can follow up with Ling on the issue linked there on github it'll be great. She knows more than I do about powershell in functions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone battling with this or similar issues within an Azure PowerShell Function, the resolution for me was to switch from using a password-based credential for the service principal to leveraging a certificate-based credential. This still does not explain the inconsistency I experienced, but at least it is now solidly consistent.